# Automatically copy items from the last list

Tags: environments, enumerate, automation

In crypto, proof involves a sequence of games. Each game contains a list of lines. Adjacent games are almost the same except for a small number of lines (usually 1). I used to copy the old game to the next one and modify on the new one. But this is really inconvenient and hard to maintain. The resulting source file is also unnecessarily large. Just think of a proof with 20 games and each of them has 10 lines.

So, I decided to create an environment for this. It looks like an "enumerate" environment where each of its items is also an "enumerate" environment. Every time I create a new item (game) for the outer enumerator, I'll also specify as a variadic parameter which lines of the last game I want to change. I want the environment itself copys every line from the last game that is not specified in the parameter automatically.

Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Could you include a(n external) source for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Section 6.1 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/588.pdf, starting from page 17. This example might be too complicated since it has an additional level of enumerate starting from Game 4. But this is not necessary and all games can be written as just a simple list.

Comment: This seems “easy” with `expl3`, but, for instance, in order to define the first time the list it would be easier if the item was an argument to the `\item` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a small fight with it (first time using `prop`) I think this works, although it's a bit of a mix of things, and may it would be better to think of a better “user interface”.

First, you have an environment `cryptolist` which is like an `enumerate` except that `\item{…}` does have an argument. `cryptolist` has an optional argument which is the *name of the list* (by default it's `default`) which gives you the option to mantain many different lists at the same time.

Then there are two commands `\replacecryptoitems` (the name in the optional argument and a usual key-value list of the items to replace) and `\printcryptolist` (the name in the optional argument). For instance you can `\replacecryptoitems{2=Modified second item, 3=modified third item}` and then `\printcryptolist` to print it.

To initialise a new crypto list you need `\newcryptolist{name}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse,enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \newcryptolist { m }
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_cryptolist_#1_prop }
  \int_new:c  { g_cryptolist_#1_int  }
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment { cryptolist } { O{default} }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_cryptolist_name_tl { #1 }
  \int_gzero:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _int }
  \prop_gclear:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _prop }
  \enumerate
   \cs_set_eq:NN \normalitem \item
   \cs_set_eq:NN \item \cryptoitem
 }
 { \endenumerate }
\NewDocumentCommand \cryptoitem { o m }
 {
  \int_gincr:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _int }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_cryptolist_item_tl
   { \int_use:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _int } }
  \prop_gput:con { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _prop }
   { \l_cryptolist_item_tl }
   { #2 }
  \IfValueTF { #1 } { \normalitem [ #1 ] } { \normalitem }
  #2
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \printcryptolist { O{default} }
 { \cc_printitems:n { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand \replacecryptoitems { O{default} m }
 { \cc_replaceitems:nn { #1 } { #2 } }

\tl_new:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl
\tl_new:N \l_cryptolist_item_tl
\prop_new:N \g_cryptolist_default_prop
\int_new:N  \g_cryptolist_default_int
\keys_define:nn { cryptolist }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \prop_gput:cVn { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _prop }
    \l_keys_key_tl { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cc_printitems:n #1
 {
  \begin{enumerate}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_cryptolist_name_tl { #1 }
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 }
     { \int_use:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _int } }
     {
      \item
      \prop_item:cn { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _prop }
       { ##1 }
     }
  \end{enumerate}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cc_replaceitems:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_cryptolist_name_tl { #1 }
  \keys_set:nn { cryptolist } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcryptolist{anotherlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{cryptolist}[anotherlist]
  \item{First item to be used later;}
  \item{second item.}
\end{cryptolist}

\begin{cryptolist}
  \item{First item}
  \item{Second item}
  \item{Third item}
  \item{Last item}
\end{cryptolist}

\replacecryptoitems{2 = Second (modified) item, 4 = Last modified item.}
\printcryptolist

\replacecryptoitems[anotherlist]{1=Changing the first one to be used now;}
\printcryptolist[anotherlist]

\end{document}
```

---

Extended code to help the new request. In this case, each time you use `\replacecryptoitems` the replaced entries are recorded. And the next time `\printcryptoitems` is given (*only* the next time, after one usage it's reset) the changed entries are `\gamediff{…}`ed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse,enumitem}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \gamediff { m }
 { \textcolor { Tomato3 } { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand \newcryptolist { m }
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_cryptolist_#1_prop }
  \int_new:c  { g_cryptolist_#1_int  }
  \seq_new:c  { g_cryptolist_modifieditems_#1_seq  }
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment { cryptolist } { O{default} }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_cryptolist_name_tl { #1 }
  \int_gzero:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _int }
  \prop_gclear:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _prop }
  \enumerate[noitemsep]
   \cs_set_eq:NN \normalitem \item
   \cs_set_eq:NN \item \cryptoitem
 }
 { \endenumerate }
\NewDocumentCommand \cryptoitem { o m }
 {
  \int_gincr:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _int }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_cryptolist_item_tl
   { \int_use:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _int } }
  \prop_gput:con { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _prop }
   { \l_cryptolist_item_tl }
   { #2 }
  \IfValueTF { #1 } { \normalitem [ #1 ] } { \normalitem }
  #2
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \printcryptolist { O{default} }
 { \cc_printitems:n { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand \replacecryptoitems { O{default} m }
 { \cc_replaceitems:nn { #1 } { #2 } }

\tl_new:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl
\tl_new:N \l_cryptolist_item_tl
\prop_new:N \g_cryptolist_default_prop
\seq_new:N \g_cryptolist_modifieditems_default_seq
\int_new:N  \g_cryptolist_default_int
\keys_define:nn { cryptolist }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \seq_gput_right:cV
    { g_cryptolist_modifieditems_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _seq }
    \l_keys_key_tl
   \prop_gput:cVn { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _prop }
    \l_keys_key_tl { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cc_printitems:n #1
 {
  \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
    \tl_set:Nn \l_cryptolist_name_tl { #1 }
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 }
     { \int_use:c { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _int } }
     {
      \item
      \group_begin:
      \seq_if_in:cnF
       { g_cryptolist_modifieditems_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _seq }
       { ##1 }
       { \cs_set_eq:NN \gamediff \prg_do_nothing: }
      {
       \prop_item:cn { g_cryptolist_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _prop }
        { ##1 }
      }
      \group_end:
     }
  \end{enumerate}
  \seq_gclear:c
   { g_cryptolist_modifieditems_ \tl_use:N \l_cryptolist_name_tl _seq }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cc_replaceitems:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_cryptolist_name_tl { #1 }
  \keys_set:nn { cryptolist } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcryptolist{anotherlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{cryptolist}
  \item{First item}
  \item{Second item}
  \item{Third item}
  \item{Last item}
\end{cryptolist}

\replacecryptoitems{2 = Second \gamediff{(modified)} item, 4 = Last modified \gamediff{item}.}
\printcryptolist

And this next time they are not highlighted.
\printcryptolist

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{expl3}

\newcommand\gamediff[2][red]{\color{#1}{\underline{\color{black}{#2}}}\color{black}{}}
\newsavebox\MBox
\newcommand\gamediffeq[2][red]{{\sbox\MBox{$#2$}\rlap{\usebox\MBox}\color{#1}\rule[-1.2\dp\MBox]{\wd\MBox}{0.5pt}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_crypto__gameseq_seq
\tl_new:N \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
\int_new:N \g_crypto__gameseq_i
\cs_new:Npn \crypto__gameseq_move:ccn #1#2#3
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #3 }
      {
        \seq_gpop_left:cN { #1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
        \seq_gput_left:cV { #2 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto__gameseq_store:cn #1#2
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_move:ccn { #1 } { g_crypto__gameseq_seq } { #2 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto__gameseq_load:cn #1#2
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_move:ccn { g_crypto__gameseq_seq } { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto__gameseq_out:N #1
  {
    \item \tl_use:N #1
  }

\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_new:c #1
  {
    \seq_gclear_new:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 }
    \int_gzero_new:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1_num }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_add:cnn #1#2#3
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_store:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } }
    \seq_gput_left:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #3 }
    \crypto__gameseq_load:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_del:cnn #1#2#3
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_store:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } }
    \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
    \crypto__gameseq_load:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_mod:cnn #1#2#3
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_store:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } }
    \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
    \seq_gput_left:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #3 }
    \crypto__gameseq_load:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_get:c #1
  {
    \int_gincr:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1_num }
    \item[Game~\int_use:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1_num }.]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \seq_map_function:cN { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } \crypto__gameseq_out:N
    \end{enumerate}
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \seqnew \crypto_gameseq_new:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \seqout \crypto_gameseq_get:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \seqadd \crypto_gameseq_add:cnn
\cs_new_eq:NN \seqdel \crypto_gameseq_del:cnn
\cs_new_eq:NN \seqmod \crypto_gameseq_mod:cnn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\seqnew{cc}
\seqadd{cc}{1}{first item}
\seqadd{cc}{2}{third item}
\seqadd{cc}{2}{fourth item}
\seqout{cc}
\seqmod{cc}{2}{\gamediff{second} item}
\seqout{cc}
\seqout{cc}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

To solve the first problem, I changed to use `seq` instead of `prop`. And the result is
[image]

But I didn't figure out how I could solve the second problem. I have two ideas:

1. Each time a game is printed out, go though all items and remove all calls to `gamediff`. The obstacle is `gamediff` might not be at the topmost level. It can be `{{gamediff}}` or `$gamediff$`.
2. when store an item into the list, the user doesn't call `gamediff` directly, but calls a function which will generate `gamediff[i]` where `i` is the current game. And when a game is printed out, `gamediff` is evaluated and only those with the first parameter equal to the current game will hightlight its content.

---

With Manuel's idea, problem 2 is also handled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{expl3}

\newcommand\highlight[2][red]{\color{#1}{\underline{\color{black}{#2}}}\color{black}{}}
\newsavebox\MBox
\newcommand\highlighteq[2][red]{{\sbox\MBox{$#2$}\rlap{\usebox\MBox}\color{#1}\rule[-1.2\dp\MBox]{\wd\MBox}{0.5pt}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_crypto__gameseq_seq
\tl_new:N \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
\int_new:N \g_crypto__gameseq_i
\cs_new:Npn \crypto__gameseq_move:ccn #1#2#3
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \int_eval:n { \int_eval:n { #3 } * 2 } }
      {
        \seq_gpop_left:cN { #1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
        \seq_gput_left:cV { #2 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto__gameseq_store:cn #1#2
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_move:ccn { #1 } { g_crypto__gameseq_seq } { #2 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto__gameseq_load:cn #1#2
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_move:ccn { g_crypto__gameseq_seq } { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_new:c #1
  {
    \seq_gclear_new:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 }
    \int_gzero_new:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1_num }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_add:cnn #1#2#3
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_store:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #2 - 1 }
    \seq_gput_left:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #3 }
    \seq_gput_left:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { 1 }
    \crypto__gameseq_load:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #2 - 1 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_del:cnn #1#2
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_store:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #2 - 1 }
    \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
    \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
    \crypto__gameseq_load:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #2 - 1 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_mod:cnn #1#2#3
  {
    \crypto__gameseq_store:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #2 - 1 }
    \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
    \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
    \seq_gput_left:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #3 }
    \seq_gput_left:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { 1 }
    \crypto__gameseq_load:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { #2 - 1 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crypto_gameseq_get:c #1
  {
    \int_gincr:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1_num }
    \item[Game~\int_use:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1_num }.]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \int_step_variable:nnnNn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:c { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } } \g_crypto__gameseq_i
      {
        \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
        \int_if_odd:nTF \g_crypto__gameseq_i
          {
            \tl_if_empty:NTF { \g_crypto__gameseq_tl }
              {
                \cs_set_eq:NN \gamediff \prg_do_nothing:
                \cs_set_eq:NN \gamediffeq \prg_do_nothing:
              }
              {
                \cs_set_eq:NN \gamediff \highlight
                \cs_set_eq:NN \gamediffeq \highlighteq
              }
            \seq_gput_left:Nn \g_crypto__gameseq_seq {}
          }
          {
            \item \tl_use:N \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
            \seq_gput_left:cV { g_crypto__gameseq_seq } \g_crypto__gameseq_tl
          }
      }
    \crypto__gameseq_load:cn { g_crypto_gameseq_#1 } { \int_eval:n { \seq_count:c { g_crypto__gameseq_seq } / 2 } }
    \end{enumerate}
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \seqnew \crypto_gameseq_new:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \seqout \crypto_gameseq_get:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \seqadd \crypto_gameseq_add:cnn
\cs_new_eq:NN \seqdel \crypto_gameseq_del:cnn
\cs_new_eq:NN \seqmod \crypto_gameseq_mod:cnn
\cs_new_eq:NN \gamediff \highlight
\cs_new_eq:NN \gamediffeq \highlighteq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\seqnew{cc}
\seqadd{cc}{1}{first item}
\seqout{cc}
\seqadd{cc}{2}{\gamediff{third} item}
\seqout{cc}
\seqadd{cc}{2}{fourth item}
\seqout{cc}
\seqmod{cc}{2}{\gamediff{second} item}
\seqout{cc}
\seqout{cc}
\seqdel{cc}{2}
\seqout{cc}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The result is[image]